# How can I find files from other partition running Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

I have two hard drives, one where Windows 7(C) is installed and the other Ubuntu 12.04(D).

I can't find the other files on `D` (like movies) using Ubuntu. But I do find them running Windows.

How can I find the files running Ubuntu without having to copy them over to C?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your partition isn't mounted on your Ubuntu system.
Type

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and there you can show all partition table, types, sizes. You can mount using

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXX
```

where XX is number of partion (eg. sda5).

After you mount partion you can access all files from it.